how to debug errors that are not pointed out by the validation layer?
I am trying Vulkan for the first time. I have never done any graphics Programming ever.
I know I should probably start from something simpler like openGL instead but vulkan just felt like it would be better if I learn just a little bit of vulkan and just get a simple gradient hello triangle on the screen, but I kinda failed and I don't really know how to debug anything that the validation layer not point out either, cause I was only able to get the basics down.
I wrote some pretty crappy c++ code but I was successful at getting something on the screen, a blue triangle, which felt pretty good, but the thing is that it was supposed to be gradient so i tried to switch things here and there but nothing really happen, so I just wanted some help from the professionals or just professional enough to point out my mistakes.
I would also like you would tell me about any tools or methods to debug problems like this that are not pointed out by the Validation Layer.
here is my crappy code :
#define GLFW_INCLUDE_VULKAN
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <bitset>

struct Position {float a, b;};
struct Color {float r, g, b;};

struct Vertex {Position pos; Color col;};

Vertex vertices[] = {
    {{0.0, -0.5},{1.0, 0.0, 0.0}},
    {{0.5, 0.5},{0.0, 1.0, 0.0}},
    {{-0.5, 0.5},{0.0, 0.0, 1.0}}
};

int main(){

    glfwInit();
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CLIENT_API, GLFW_NO_API);
    uint32_t count; glfwGetRequiredInstanceExtensions(&count);
    VkInstance instance = 0; {
        const char* layers[] = {
            "VK_LAYER_KHRONOS_validation"
        };
        VkInstanceCreateInfo info = {
            .sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_INSTANCE_CREATE_INFO,
            .enabledLayerCount = 1,
            .ppEnabledLayerNames = layers,
            .enabledExtensionCount = 2,
            .ppEnabledExtensionNames = glfwGetRequiredInstanceExtensions(&count)
        }; vkCreateInstance(&info, 0, &instance);
    }

    VkDevice device = 0;
    VkPhysicalDevice gpu = 0;  {
        {
            uint32_t count = 1; vkEnumeratePhysicalDevices(instance, &count, &gpu);
        }
        float prior[] = {1.0f};
        VkDeviceQueueCreateInfo queues[] = {
            {
                .sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_DEVICE_QUEUE_CREATE_INFO,
                .queueFamilyIndex = 0,
                .queueCount = 1,
                .pQueuePriorities = prior
            }
        };
        
        const char* exts[] = {
            VK_KHR_SWAPCHAIN_EXTENSION_NAME
        };
        VkDeviceCreateInfo info = {
            .sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_DEVICE_CREATE_INFO,
            .queueCreateInfoCount = 1,
            .pQueueCreateInfos = queues,
            .enabledExtensionCount = 1,
            .ppEnabledExtensionNames = exts
        }; vkCreateDevice(gpu, &info, 0, &device);
    }

    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(1000, 600, "tt", 0, 0);
    VkSurfaceKHR surface = 0; {
        glfwCreateWindowSurface(instance, window, 0, &surface);
    }

    VkSwapchainKHR swapchain = 0; {
        VkSurfaceCapabilitiesKHR  capa;
        vkGetPhysicalDeviceSurfaceCapabilitiesKHR(gpu, surface, &capa);
        VkSwapchainCreateInfoKHR info = {
            .sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_SWAPCHAIN_CREATE_INFO_KHR,
            .surface = surface,
            .minImageCount = 2,
            .imageFormat = VK_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM,
            .imageColorSpace = VK_COLORSPACE_SRGB_NONLINEAR_KHR,
            .imageExtent = capa.currentExtent,
            .imageArrayLayers = 1,
            .imageUsage = VK_IMAGE_USAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_BIT,
            .imageSharingMode = VK_SHARING_MODE_EXCLUSIVE,
            .preTransform = capa.currentTransform,
            .compositeAlpha = VK_COMPOSITE_ALPHA_OPAQUE_BIT_KHR,
            .presentMode = VK_PRESENT_MODE_FIFO_KHR,
            .clipped = VK_TRUE,
        }; vkCreateSwapchainKHR(device, &info, 0, &swapchain);
    }
    std::vector<VkImageView> swapchain_views;{
        uint32_t count = 0;
        vkGetSwapchainImagesKHR(device, swapchain, &count, 0);
        std::vector<VkImage> swapchain_images(count); swapchain_views.resize(count);
        vkGetSwapchainImagesKHR(device, swapchain, &count, swapchain_images.data());
        VkImageViewCreateInfo info = {
            .sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_IMAGE_VIEW_CREATE_INFO,
            .viewType = VK_IMAGE_VIEW_TYPE_2D,
            .format = VK_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM,
            .components = {
                VK_COMPONENT_SWIZZLE_IDENTITY, 
                VK_COMPONENT_SWIZZLE_IDENTITY, 
                VK_COMPONENT_SWIZZLE_IDENTITY, 
                VK_COMPONENT_SWIZZLE_IDENTITY
            },
            .subresourceRange = {
                .aspectMask = VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_COLOR_BIT,
                .baseMipLevel = 0,
                .levelCount = 1,
                .baseArrayLayer = 0,
                .layerCount = 1
            }
        };
        
        count = 0; for(auto&image:swapchain_images){
            info.image = image;
            vkCreateImageView(device, &info, 0, &swapchain_views[count]);
            count+=1;
        }
    }
    VkRenderPass renderpass = 0; {
        VkAttachmentDescription attachments[] = {
            {
                .format = VK_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM,
                .samples = VK_SAMPLE_COUNT_1_BIT,
                .loadOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_CLEAR,
                .storeOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_STORE_OP_STORE,
                .stencilLoadOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_DONT_CARE,
                .stencilStoreOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_STORE_OP_DONT_CARE,
                .initialLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED,
                .finalLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_PRESENT_SRC_KHR
            }
        };
        VkAttachmentReference ref[] = {
            {
                .attachment = 0,
                .layout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL
            }
        };
        VkSubpassDescription subpasses[] = {
            {
                .pipelineBindPoint = VK_PIPELINE_BIND_POINT_GRAPHICS,
                .colorAttachmentCount = 1,
                .pColorAttachments = ref,
            }
        };
        VkSubpassDependency dependencies[] = {
            {
                .srcSubpass = VK_SUBPASS_EXTERNAL,
                .dstSubpass = 0,
                .srcStageMask = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT,
                .dstStageMask = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT,
                .srcAccessMask = 0,
                .dstAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_WRITE_BIT,
                .dependencyFlags = 0
            }
        };
        VkRenderPassCreateInfo info = {
            .sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_RENDER_PASS_CREATE_INFO,
            .attachmentCount = 1,
            .pAttachments = attachments,
            .subpassCount = 1,
            .pSubpasses = subpasses,
            .dependencyCount = 1,
            .pDependencies = dependencies
        }; vkCreateRenderPass(device, &info, 0, &renderpass);
    }
    VkShaderModule vert;{
        std::fstream file("vert.spv", std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
        std::stringstream oss; oss << file.rdbuf();
        auto str = oss.str();
        VkShaderModuleCreateInfo info = {
            .sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_SHADER_MODULE_CREATE_INFO,
            .codeSize = str.size(),
            .pCode = reinterpret_cast<const uint32_t*>(str.data())
        }; if(file.is_open()) vkCreateShaderModule(device, &info, 0, &vert); else std::cout<<"no vert shader\n";
    }
    VkShaderModule frag;{
        std::fstream file("frag.spv", std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
        std::stringstream oss; oss << file.rdbuf();
        auto str = oss.str();
        VkShaderModuleCreateInfo info = {
            .sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_SHADER_MODULE_CREATE_INFO,
            .codeSize = str.size(),
            .pCode = reinterpret_cast<const uint32_t*>(str.data())
        }; if(file.is_open()) vkCreateShaderModule(device, &info, 0, &frag); else std::cout<<"no frag shader\n";
    }
    VkPipelineLayout layout = 0; {
        VkPipelineLayoutCreateInfo info = {
            .sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_LAYOUT_CREATE_INFO
        }; vkCreatePipelineLayout(device, &info, 0, &layout);
    }
    VkPipeline gfx_pipeline = 0; {
        VkPipelineShaderStageCreateInfo stages[] = {
            {
                .sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_SHADER_STAGE_CREATE_INFO,
                .stage = VkShaderStageFlagBits::VK_SHADER_STAGE_VERTEX_BIT,
                .module = vert,
                .pName = "main"
            },
            {
                .sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_SHADER_STAGE_CREATE_INFO,
                .stage = VkShaderStageFlagBits::VK_SHADER_STAGE_FRAGMENT_BIT,
                .module = frag,
                .pName = "main"
            }
        }; VkVertexInputBindingDescription vert_bind_desc[] = {
            {
                .binding = 0,
                .stride = sizeof(Vertex),
                .inputRate = VK_VERTEX_INPUT_RATE_VERTEX
            }
        }; VkVertexInputAttributeDescription vert_attr_desc[] ={
            {
                .location = 0,
                .binding = 0,
                .format = VK_FORMAT_R32G32_SFLOAT,
                .offset = offsetof(Vertex, pos)
            },
            {
                .location = 1,
                .binding = 0,
                .format = VK_FORMAT_R8G8B8_UNORM,
                .offset = offsetof(Vertex, col)
            }
        }; VkPipelineVertexInputStateCreateInfo vertexInputs[] = {
            {
                .sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_VERTEX_INPUT_STATE_CREATE_INFO,
                .vertexBindingDescriptionCount = 1,
                .pVertexBindingDescriptions = vert_bind_desc,
                .vertexAttributeDescriptionCount = 2,
                .pVertexAttributeDescriptions = vert_attr_desc
            }
        }; VkPipelineInputAssemblyStateCreateInfo inputAssembly[] = {
            {
                .sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_INPUT_ASSEMBLY_STATE_CREATE_INFO,
                .topology = VK_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLE_LIST
            }
        }; VkPipelineViewportStateCreateInfo viewport[] = {
            {
                .sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_VIEWPORT_STATE_CREATE_INFO,
                .viewportCount = 1,
                .scissorCount = 1,
            }
        }; VkPipelineRasterizationStateCreateInfo raterizer[] = {
            {
                .sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_RASTERIZATION_STATE_CREATE_INFO,
                .polygonMode = VK_POLYGON_MODE_FILL,
                .cullMode = VK_CULL_MODE_BACK_BIT,
                .frontFace = VK_FRONT_FACE_CLOCKWISE,
                .lineWidth = 1.
            }
        }; VkPipelineMultisampleStateCreateInfo multisample[] = {
            {
                .sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_MULTISAMPLE_STATE_CREATE_INFO,
                .rasterizationSamples = VK_SAMPLE_COUNT_1_BIT
            }
        }; VkPipelineColorBlendAttachmentState colorblendAtt[] = {
            {
                .colorWriteMask = VK_COLOR_COMPONENT_R_BIT | VK_COLOR_COMPONENT_G_BIT | VK_COLOR_COMPONENT_B_BIT | VK_COLOR_COMPONENT_A_BIT,
            }
        };
        VkPipelineColorBlendStateCreateInfo colorblend[] = {
            {
                .sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_COLOR_BLEND_STATE_CREATE_INFO,
                .logicOp = VK_LOGIC_OP_COPY,
                .attachmentCount = 1,
                .pAttachments = colorblendAtt,
                .blendConstants = {.0, .0, .0, .0}
            }
        }; VkDynamicState dynamic_states[] = {VK_DYNAMIC_STATE_VIEWPORT, VK_DYNAMIC_STATE_SCISSOR};

        VkPipelineDynamicStateCreateInfo dynamics[] = {
            {
                .sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_DYNAMIC_STATE_CREATE_INFO,
                .dynamicStateCount = 2,
                .pDynamicStates = dynamic_states,
            }
        }; 
        VkGraphicsPipelineCreateInfo info = {
            .sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_GRAPHICS_PIPELINE_CREATE_INFO,
            .stageCount = 2,
            .pStages = stages,
            .pVertexInputState = vertexInputs,
            .pInputAssemblyState = inputAssembly,
            .pTessellationState = 0,
            .pViewportState = viewport,
            .pRasterizationState = raterizer,
            .pMultisampleState = multisample,
            .pDepthStencilState = 0,
            .pColorBlendState = colorblend,
            .pDynamicState = dynamics,
            .layout = layout,
            .renderPass = renderpass,
            .subpass = 0,
            .basePipelineHandle = 0,
            .basePipelineIndex = -1
        }; vkCreateGraphicsPipelines(device, 0, 1, &info, 0, &gfx_pipeline);
    }
    std::vector<VkFramebuffer> framebuffers(swapchain_views.size()); {
        int width, height;
        glfwGetFramebufferSize(window, &width, &height);
        VkFramebufferCreateInfo info = {
            .sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_FRAMEBUFFER_CREATE_INFO,
            .renderPass = renderpass,
            .attachmentCount = 1,
            .width = static_cast<uint32_t>(width),
            .height = static_cast<uint32_t>(height),
            .layers = 1
        }; uint32_t count = 0; for(auto&view:swapchain_views){
            info.pAttachments = &view;
            vkCreateFramebuffer(device, &info, 0, &framebuffers[count]);
            count+=1;
        }
    }

    VkQueue queue = 0; {
        vkGetDeviceQueue(device, 0, 0, &queue);
    }
    VkCommandPool pool = 0; {
        VkCommandPoolCreateInfo info = {
            .sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_COMMAND_POOL_CREATE_INFO,
            .flags = VK_COMMAND_POOL_CREATE_RESET_COMMAND_BUFFER_BIT,
            .queueFamilyIndex = 0
        }; vkCreateCommandPool(device, &info, 0, &pool);
    }
    std::vector<VkCommandBuffer> commandBuffers(framebuffers.size()); {
        VkCommandBufferAllocateInfo info = {
            .sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_COMMAND_BUFFER_ALLOCATE_INFO,
            .commandPool = pool,
            .level = VK_COMMAND_BUFFER_LEVEL_PRIMARY,
            .commandBufferCount = 2
        }; vkAllocateCommandBuffers(device, &info, commandBuffers.data());
    }

    std::vector<VkFence> imgPresented(framebuffers.size()); {
        VkFenceCreateInfo info = {
            .sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_FENCE_CREATE_INFO,
            .flags = VK_FENCE_CREATE_SIGNALED_BIT
        }; for(auto&fence:imgPresented) vkCreateFence(device, &info, 0, &fence);
    }
    std::vector<VkSemaphore> renderFinished(framebuffers.size());
    std::vector<VkSemaphore> imageAccquired(framebuffers.size()); {
        VkSemaphoreCreateInfo info = {
            .sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_SEMAPHORE_CREATE_INFO
        };
        for(auto&sema:renderFinished) vkCreateSemaphore(device, &info, 0, &sema);
        for(auto&sema:imageAccquired) vkCreateSemaphore(device, &info, 0, &sema);
    }

    std::unordered_map<VkMemoryPropertyFlags ,const char*> memories(6);{
        memories[VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_DEVICE_LOCAL_BIT] = "DEVICE_LOCAL";
        memories[VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_VISIBLE_BIT] = "HOST_VISIBLE";
        memories[VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_COHERENT_BIT] = "HOST_COHERENT";
        memories[VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_CACHED_BIT] = "HOST_CACHED";
        memories[VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_LAZILY_ALLOCATED_BIT] = "LAZILY_ALLOCATED";
        memories[VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_PROTECTED_BIT] = "PROTECTED";

    }
            
    auto types = [&memories](VkMemoryPropertyFlags flag) -> std::string {
        std::string str = ""; uint32_t bit = 1;
        for(uint32_t i = 1; i<32;i++){
            if(flag&bit) str = str + memories[bit] + " ";
            bit=bit<<1;
        }
        return str;
    };

    std::unordered_map<VkMemoryMapFlags, uint32_t> mem_indices; {
        VkPhysicalDeviceMemoryProperties memory_properties;
        vkGetPhysicalDeviceMemoryProperties(gpu, &memory_properties);
        mem_indices.reserve(memory_properties.memoryTypeCount);
        for(int i=0;i<memory_properties.memoryTypeCount;i++){
            mem_indices[memory_properties.memoryTypes[i].propertyFlags]=i;
        } std::cout<<"memory types : \n";

        for(auto&pair:mem_indices){
            std::bitset<sizeof(decltype(memory_properties.memoryTypes[0].propertyFlags))*8> the_bits(pair.first);
            std::cout<<"\tat index|"<<pair.second<<"| : "<<the_bits<<" ( "<<types(pair.first)<<")"<<std::endl;
        }
    }

    VkDeviceMemory vertexMemory = 0;
    VkBuffer vertexBuffer = 0; {
        VkBufferCreateInfo info = {
            .sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_BUFFER_CREATE_INFO,
            .size = sizeof(vertices),
            .usage = VK_BUFFER_USAGE_VERTEX_BUFFER_BIT,
            .sharingMode = VK_SHARING_MODE_EXCLUSIVE
        }; vkCreateBuffer(device, &info, 0, &vertexBuffer);
        VkMemoryRequirements requirements;
        vkGetBufferMemoryRequirements(device, vertexBuffer, &requirements);
        if(mem_indices.find(requirements.memoryTypeBits|VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_VISIBLE_BIT|VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_COHERENT_BIT)==mem_indices.end()) goto CLEAN;
        std::cout<<"required : "<<types(requirements.memoryTypeBits)<<std::endl;
        std::cout<<"requesting : "<< types(requirements.memoryTypeBits|VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_VISIBLE_BIT|VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_COHERENT_BIT)<<std::endl;
        VkMemoryAllocateInfo alloc_info = {
            .sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_MEMORY_ALLOCATE_INFO,
            .allocationSize = requirements.size,
            .memoryTypeIndex = mem_indices[requirements.memoryTypeBits|VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_VISIBLE_BIT|VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_COHERENT_BIT]
        }; vkAllocateMemory(device, &alloc_info, 0, &vertexMemory);
        VkPhysicalDeviceFeatures feat; vkGetPhysicalDeviceFeatures(gpu, &feat);
        
        void* data = 0;

        vkMapMemory(device, vertexMemory, 0, sizeof(vertices), 0, &data);
        memcpy(data, vertices, sizeof(vertices));
        vkUnmapMemory(device, vertexMemory);
        vkBindBufferMemory(device, vertexBuffer, vertexMemory, 0);
    }
    VkRect2D extent; {
        int width, height;
        glfwGetFramebufferSize(window, &width, &height);
        extent = {
            .offset = {
                .x = 0,
                .y = 0
            },
            .extent = {
                .width = static_cast<uint32_t>(width),
                .height = static_cast<uint32_t>(height)
            }
        };
    }
    VkViewport viewport{
        .x = 0,
        .y = 0,
        .width = (float)extent.extent.width,
        .height = (float)extent.extent.height,
        .minDepth = .0,
        .maxDepth = 1.
    };
    VkRect2D scissor{
        .offset = {0, 0},
        .extent = extent.extent
    };
    uint32_t curr = 0;
    while(!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)){
        glfwPollEvents();
        vkWaitForFences(device, 1, &imgPresented[curr], VK_TRUE, UINT64_MAX);
        vkResetFences(device, 1, &imgPresented[curr]);
        uint32_t imgIndex;
        vkAcquireNextImageKHR(device, swapchain, UINT64_MAX, imageAccquired[curr], 0, &imgIndex);
        vkResetCommandBuffer(commandBuffers[curr], 0);
        VkCommandBufferBeginInfo begin = {
            .sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_COMMAND_BUFFER_BEGIN_INFO,
        }; 
        vkBeginCommandBuffer(commandBuffers[curr], &begin); VkClearValue clearColor = {{{0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f}}};
        VkRenderPassBeginInfo renderpass_info = {
            .sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_RENDER_PASS_BEGIN_INFO,
            .renderPass = renderpass,
            .framebuffer = framebuffers[imgIndex],
            .renderArea = {
                .offset = {0, 0},
                .extent = extent.extent
            },
            .clearValueCount = 1,
            .pClearValues = &clearColor
        }; 
        vkCmdBeginRenderPass(commandBuffers[curr], &renderpass_info, VK_SUBPASS_CONTENTS_INLINE);
        vkCmdBindPipeline(commandBuffers[curr], VK_PIPELINE_BIND_POINT_GRAPHICS, gfx_pipeline);
        vkCmdSetViewport(commandBuffers[curr], 0, 1, &viewport); vkCmdSetScissor(commandBuffers[curr], 0, 1, &scissor);
        VkDeviceSize offsets[]{0};
        vkCmdBindVertexBuffers(commandBuffers[curr], 0, 1, &vertexBuffer, offsets);
        vkCmdDraw(commandBuffers[curr], 3, 1, 0, 0);
        vkCmdEndRenderPass(commandBuffers[curr]);
        vkEndCommandBuffer(commandBuffers[curr]); VkPipelineStageFlags flag = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT;
        VkSubmitInfo submitInfo{
            .sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_SUBMIT_INFO,
            .waitSemaphoreCount = 1,
            .pWaitSemaphores = &imageAccquired[curr],
            .pWaitDstStageMask = &flag,
            .commandBufferCount = 1,
            .pCommandBuffers = &commandBuffers[curr],
            .signalSemaphoreCount = 1,
            .pSignalSemaphores = &renderFinished[curr]
        };
        vkQueueSubmit(queue, 1, &submitInfo, imgPresented[curr]);
        VkPresentInfoKHR presentInfo{
            .sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PRESENT_INFO_KHR,
            .waitSemaphoreCount = 1,
            .pWaitSemaphores = &renderFinished[curr],
            .swapchainCount = 1,
            .pSwapchains = &swapchain,
            .pImageIndices = &imgIndex
        };
        vkQueuePresentKHR(queue, &presentInfo);
        curr = (curr + 1) % 2;
    }

    vkQueueWaitIdle(queue);
    vkDeviceWaitIdle(device);

    vkFreeMemory(device, vertexMemory, 0);

CLEAN:
    vkDestroyBuffer(device, vertexBuffer, 0);
    for(auto&fence:imgPresented) vkDestroyFence(device, fence, 0);
    for(auto&sema:renderFinished) vkDestroySemaphore(device, sema, 0);
    for(auto&sema:imageAccquired) vkDestroySemaphore(device, sema, 0);
    vkFreeCommandBuffers(device, pool, 2, commandBuffers.data());
    vkDestroyCommandPool(device, pool, 0);
    vkDestroyPipeline(device, gfx_pipeline, 0);
    vkDestroyPipelineLayout(device, layout, 0);
    vkDestroyRenderPass(device, renderpass, 0);
    vkDestroyShaderModule(device, vert, 0);
    vkDestroyShaderModule(device, frag, 0);
    for(auto&frame:framebuffers) vkDestroyFramebuffer(device, frame, 0);
    for(auto&view:swapchain_views) vkDestroyImageView(device, view, 0);
    vkDestroySwapchainKHR(device, swapchain, 0);
    vkDestroyDevice(device, 0);
    vkDestroySurfaceKHR(instance, surface, 0);
    glfwDestroyWindow(window);
    vkDestroyInstance(instance, 0);
    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}

the vertex shader :
#version 450

layout(location = 0) in vec2 inPos;
layout(location = 1) in vec3 inCol;
layout(location = 0) out vec3 fragColor;

void main(){
    gl_Position = vec4(inPos, 0.0, 1.0);
    fragColor = inCol;
}

the fragment shader :
#version 450

layout(location = 0) in vec3 fragColor;
layout(location = 0) out vec4 outCol;

void main(){
    outCol = vec4(fragColor, 1.0);
}


Your color type:

struct Color {float r, g, b;};

doesn't match the vertex format you've specified:

VK_FORMAT_R8G8B8_UNORM

The size of your actual color structure is 12 bytes, but your pipeline is only looking at the first 3 bytes of the structure, and converting them to a color based on the 0-255 value of each one.
Since the first color has a red value of 1.0, it has a binary value of 0x3f800000.

However, your processor is almost certainly little-endian so it will actually be laid out in memory like this 0x0000803f, and since the you told it the format is 8-bit based, the upload to the GPU will leave it in that little-endian layout.
When this gets interpreted by the shader it will see r: 0x00, g: 0x00, b: 0x80, and since you're using a UNORM format that gets mapped to vec3(0, 0, 0.5), or dark blue.
Either change the color format to VK_FORMAT_R3232B32_SFLOAT or change the Color type to struct Color {uint8_t r, g, b, a;};. I would avoid the temptation to use uint8_t r, g, b;, even if you have no intention of using the alpha channel, nearly everything you send to the GPU should be 32-bit aligned, or even better, 128-bit aligned.
The validation layers can't really help you with this because they have no way of knowing that your C++ structure doesn't match the format you're providing.
However, tools like Renderdoc are excellent for discovering this kind of thing because they let you examine the vertex buffer used at the time of the draw call directly.  You have to provide information about how the buffer is structured, giving you the chance to discover that the data in the buffer doesn't match the format you've sent and figure out why.
